# Denwer в глобальной сети. Не работает mysql

Tags: php, mysql, denwer

Я работаю в среде Denwer. Он выходит в интернет, и, по моему IP адресу, я могу зайти на свой сайт с любой точки мира. Но. Есть проблема с базой данных mysql. Если я не подключён к своему роутеру, на котором висит Denwer, а допустим нахожусь где-то далеко от дома, то, при выполнении PHP команды `mysql_connect('Мой IP', 'username', 'password')` всё прекрасно работает и доступ к бд есть. Но, когда я подключён к своему роутеру, то, при выполнении этой же самой команды PHP вылетает ошибка #2002 - `Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение.`. Подобных проблем в интернете найти не могу. Как устранить это проблему? Я хочу, чтобы я мог заходить на свой сайт и видеть базу данных и дома, и на улице, и где только душе угодно. Подскажите кто-нибудь решение.

Если что, подключение Apache в `cmd netstat -a` я просматривал:

```
TCP     127.0.0.1:3306     0.0.0.0    LISTENING
```

Comment: Давно уже денвером не пользовался .. попробуйте посмотреть в сторону [Open server](http://open-server.ru/) там хорошая поддержка и простой в настройке и обновляется регулярно.

Comment: В `mysql_connect('Мой IP',...` какой стоит IP? Белый или серый?

Comment: Там стоит статический. Как я Вас понял - Белый.

Comment: У вашего роутера проблемы с NAT Loopback. Какая модель?

Comment: Уточните, если можно. По модели можно узнать лечится это или нет.

Comment: Asus RTN 18U...

Comment: Вроде как лечится, но не стандартной прошивкой. Попробуйте перепрошиться на *DD-WRT*. *ASUS RT-N18U* есть в списке поддерживаемых этой прошивкой. У *DD-WRT*, насколько мне известно, таких проблем нет. Или на *Tomato*, там тоже вроде бы с NAT Loopback нет проблем. 100% нет проблем с NAT Loopback у *ASUS-WRT Merlin*, сам на ней, но она к этой модели не подходит.

Comment: Кстати! Кажется я придумал! Есть же PHP.

Comment: А прошивка-то последняя? 3.0.0.4.378.9459? Может, и официалы поправили?

Comment: Нет, прошивка у меня следующая: 3.0.0.4.374_4983

Comment: Попробуйте для начала обновиться. Вроде как ASUS мудрил что-то недавно с NAT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно сделать следующим образом.

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '192.168.1.1') { // 192.168.1.1 - Внутренний IP адрес сети
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
} else {
    mysql_connect($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], 'username', 'password');
}
```

Таким образом, данный скрипт будет знать: Если я в локальной сети, то присоединиться к базе данных по `localhost`, если в глобальной (не присоединён к роутеру), то к `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`, то есть статическому.